# Are there any official resources or websites for contract appraisal?

Tags: contract-design, contract-debugging, testing

Obviously people can post specific questions here but, since everything is open source anyway, is there a place for people to post contracts and allow other people to point out vulnerabilities or problems. Seems like a reasonable idea to help reduce faulty contracts. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the idea. I've just created a section for active bug bounties on The Ethereum Wiki at https://theethereum.wiki which is currently being built.

Comment: Of course! Splendid idea :-) (Apologies for saying nothing of any constructive value... )

Comment: Related (though only a working prototype) - StackExchange Bounty Dapp: http://dapps.oraclize.it/stackexchange-v2/#/stackexchange-v2/